# CodeIgniter: help with this query

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have just started my first CI app. I have a view that displays some posts. Each post can have multiple comments and I want to display the total number of comments next to each post.

So far all my db call are in my controller (will be changing this).

```
function index(){
    $data['query'] = $this->db->get('posts');
    $this->load->view('blog_view', $data);
}
```

In my view:

```
<?php foreach($query->result() as $row): 
      <div class="post-box">
          <p><?php echo $row->body; ?><small>&nbsp;added by <?php echo $row->username; ?> on  <?php echo date ('d/m/Y',strtotime($row->created)); ?>&nbsp;<a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>blog/comments/<?php echo $row->id; ?>"><img src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>images/comments_icon.png" />&nbsp;0</a></small></p>
      </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I want to get the total number of comments where comment.post_id = the current record's id. and display it next to the comments icon.

Any help with this most appreciated,

Billy

UPDATE

Controller:

```
function index(){
    //load the model
    $this->load->model('City_model');

    //call the model method
    $data->posts = $this->City_model->get_posts();


    $this->load->view('blog_view', $data);
}
```

Model (city_model.php):

```
<?php

class City_model extends Model{

    function get_posts($id = NULL) {

        //define optional id for single post
        //if an id was supplied
        if ( $id != NULL ) {
            $this->db->where('id',$id);
        }

        // execute query
        $query = $this->db->get('posts');

        //make sure results exist
        if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
            $posts = $query->result();
        } else {
            return FALSE;
        }

        //create array for appended (with comments) posts
        $appended_posts_array = array();

        //loop through each post
        foreach ($posts as $post) {

            //get comments associated with the post
            $this->db->where('post_id', $post->id)
            $comments = $this->db->get('comments');

            //if there are comments, add the comments to the post object
            if($comments->num_rows() > 0) {
                $post->comments = $comments;
            }
            else {
                $post->comments = array();
            }

            //rebuild the returned posts with their comments
            $appended_posts_array[] = $post;

        }

        //if post id supplied, only return the single post object
        if ($id != NULL) {
            return $appended_registration_array[0];
        }
        else {
            return $appended_registration_array;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example model method that takes the approach I usually do for Items that have "sub" items...

I generally build them in a Multi-level array in the model like so...

*Note: this model returns a post or all posts, complete with an array of associated comments accessable through the `->comments` property.*

```
function get_posts($id = NULL) {

    //define optional id for single post
    //if an id was supplied
    if ( $id != NULL ) {
        $this->db->where('id',$id);
    }

    // execute query
    $query = $this->db->get('posts');

    //make sure results exist
    if($query->num_rows() > 0) {
        $posts = $query->result();
    } else {
        return FALSE;
    }

    //create array for appended (with comments) posts
    $appended_posts_array = array();

    //loop through each post
    foreach ($posts as $post) {

        //get comments associated with the post
        $this->db->where('post_id', $post->id)
        $comments = $this->db->get('comments');

        //if there are comments, add the comments to the post object
        if($comments->num_rows() > 0) {
            $post->comments = $comments;
        }
        else {
            $post->comments = array();
        }

        //rebuild the returned posts with their comments
        $appended_posts_array[] = $post;

    }

    //if post id supplied, only return the single post object
    if ($id != NULL) {
        return $appended_registration_array[0];
    }
    else {
        return $appended_registration_array;
    }       
}
```

Now in the controller...

```
function posts() {

    //load the model
    $this->load->model('model_name');

    //call the model method
    $data->posts = $this->model_name->get_posts();

    //load the view
    $this->load->view('view/file', $data);

}
```

Then in the view you can use a nested foreach to loop through the posts AND the comments

```
<? foreach($posts as $post): ?>                //posts foreach start

    <h1><?= $post->title ?></h1>  //post title
    <p><?= $post->body ?></p>     //post body

    <? foreach($post->comments as $comment): ?>     //comments foreach start       
        <h3><?= $comment->author ?></h3>  //comment author
        <p><?= $comment->body ?></h3>     //comment body
    <? endforeach; ?>                               // end comments foreach

<? endforeach; ?>        // end posts foreach
```

Take note that once you build the posts array like I have shown in the model,  for each $post item you have a $post->comments that is simply an array of comments that are associated with that post, so knowing that, you can call `count($post->comments)` in the controller or view to get the number of comments related to a single post.

So for your question about just displaying the count, in the view the only change is that you wouldn't loop through all the comments, you'd just do this instead...

```
<? foreach($posts as $post): ?>                //posts foreach start

    <h1><?= $post->title ?></h1>             //post title
    <p><?= count($post->comments) ?></p>     //comment count


<? endforeach; ?>        // end posts foreach
```

**EDIT :** 
I added the optional parameter `$id` to the model method so that if you want you can specify a single post if you wish, by passing it's id to the method.  That way this same model method can be re-used to display single posts in detail with all comments displayed also.

Comment: @jondavidjohn: I deleted my original answer, as yours is more comprehensive and more in the MVC "spirit", so-to-speak. I agree that the OP should definitely opt for this type of solution over a "quick fix." +1 for taking the time to illustrate the proper approach.

Comment: THis looks like just what I wanted. I'll give it a go!

Comment: I tried your code. Looks like it should work fine. All the table names are correct. I've named the model correct. Added the class to the model, call the model correct but I'm getting a server error when I load the module. Module name: city_model.php calling it with $this->load->model('City_model');

Comment: first thing that jumps out at me is that you're capitalizing `City_model` when loading and using it, load it as `city_model` and use it as `$this->city_model`

Comment: Sorry I wasn't notified of your reply. No I didn't as soon as I load the model, I get a server error. Capitalized or not :(

Comment: I can't seem to load any models, even a very basic one with only a constructor

Comment: make sure it is in your system/application/models directory

Comment: Yeah I wouldn't know where else to put the. The error is "HTTP Error 500 (Internal Server Error): An unexpected condition was encountered while the server was attempting to fulfill the request."

Comment: ok, make sure your php.ini file is configured to display_errors and your error condition is set to E_ALL

Comment: That is the general error you receive if your php is isn't setup to debug per the options I pointed out.

Comment: Ok feeling rather stupid now it was a silly mistake. Somewhere along the line I had removed the $ from $this->. Probably when I was commenting the line of code out. All is well now. Thanks a lot jondavidjohn :D